# Why does exporting an interface, enum or type not create a module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following TS file (`enums.ts`) I try to import in another file

```
export interface ZZZ { 
  z: number
}

export const enum EnumTest {
  T2,
  T3,
  XY
}

export type EnumTest_Strings = keyof typeof EnumTest;

export function toto(){ }; // commenting this 'removes' the module
```

If I remove the last line, I can't import anything in the other file. It says it does not find a module "`./enums`".

Is there a way to create a module without having to declare functions?

Comment: Please show us your import in the other file.

Answer (score 2):

### For `const enum`

You will want to enable [`preserveConstEnums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveConstEnums) in your `tsconfig.json` file.

> **preserveConstEnums:** Do not erase const enum declarations in generated code. const enums provide a way to reduce the overall memory footprint of your application at runtime by emitting the enum value instead of a reference.

With `preserveConstEnums` enabled then this typescript code:

```
export interface ZZZ { 
  z: number
}

export const enum EnumTest {
  T2,
  T3,
  XY
}

export type EnumTest_Strings = keyof typeof EnumTest;
```

Will result in this javascript code:

```js
export var EnumTest;
(function (EnumTest) {
    EnumTest[EnumTest["T2"] = 0] = "T2";
    EnumTest[EnumTest["T3"] = 1] = "T3";
    EnumTest[EnumTest["XY"] = 2] = "XY";
})(EnumTest || (EnumTest = {}));
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?preserveConstEnums=true&ssl=11&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgLULgG84AoOOALwC44kBXAWwCM0yBfMs0SWObBCQBneMEZM4AUQkAVYKJIU4sgEwAaZbIDMmygA0Amp269o8GAE8weGc3miA+gGUYUZAHNhcALxwA1sCWEOhwVjYh0nIKMADcZEA)

### For regular `enum`

Alternatively you can use a regular `enum` instead of a `const enum`.

With a regular `enum` then this typescript code:

```
export interface ZZZ { 
  z: number
}

export enum EnumTest {
  T2,
  T3,
  XY
}

export type EnumTest_Strings = keyof typeof EnumTest;
```

Will result in this javascript code:

```js
export var EnumTest;
(function (EnumTest) {
    EnumTest[EnumTest["T2"] = 0] = "T2";
    EnumTest[EnumTest["T3"] = 1] = "T3";
    EnumTest[EnumTest["XY"] = 2] = "XY";
})(EnumTest || (EnumTest = {}));
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&preserveConstEnums=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgLULgG84AoOOALwC44kBXAWwCM0yBfMs0SWOYIyZwAokIAqwAM7xiFOOIBMAGnniAzKsoANAJqduvaPBgBPMHjHNJMgPoBlGFGQBzKXAC8cANbBTEdDgzCwDRCWkYAG4yIA)

### Difference between `enum` & `const enum`

Regular `enum`:s are:

- More coprehensive than `const enum`:s
- Compiled down to javascript object

`const enum`:s are:

- More restrictive then regular `enum`:s
- Compiled "away" during transpilation.

This means that `const enum`:s wont be accessible during runtime (or as part of a library), however `const enum`:s leave less of a footprint in the resulting javascript.
For example: `console.log(EnumTest.XY)` will either transpile to `console.log(EnumTest.XY)` if `EnumTest` is a regular `enum`, or it will transpile to `console.log(2 /* XY */)` if `EnumTest` is a `const enum`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&preserveConstEnums=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYXNAok5AVOaGAbwCgYY8AmAGnMoGY6KANATVIF9TSEUYASnADmiADYBDAE44UBImQrVmjFey49QkEGLgA6MSGEAKDJCiz8hKHvYBKANyktEHfsMmhoyTNzyb9g5AA)

### Regarding `interface` and `type`

These are "just" types, they won't be accessible or relevant in vanilla javascript in any shape or form, so typescript won't include them in any way in the build output by default. You can still include them in your output in the form of a type declaration if you enable [`declaration`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) in your `tsconfig.json`. This wont change your codes behavior during runtime or during interop with javascript. But it will allow other typescript files to import your transpiled javascript as if it was regular typescript.

With `declaration` enabled then this typescript code:

```
export interface ZZZ { 
  z: number
}

export enum EnumTest {
  T2,
  T3,
  XY
}

export type EnumTest_Strings = keyof typeof EnumTest;
```

Will result in this declaration file (`.d.ts`) alongside your javascript:

```
export interface ZZZ {
    z: number;
}
export declare enum EnumTest {
    T2 = 0,
    T3 = 1,
    XY = 2
}
export declare type EnumTest_Strings = keyof typeof EnumTest;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&preserveConstEnums=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgLULgG84AoOOALwC44kBXAWwCM0yBfMs0SWOYIyZwAokIAqwAM7xiFOOIBMAGnniAzKsoANAJqduvaPBgBPMHjHNJMgPoBlGFGQBzKXAC8cANbBTEdDgzCwDRCWkYAG4yIA)